# Ignore a character when using Select-String

Tags: regex, powershell, select-string

I am looking for a string of specific characters in a text file; I use

```
Select-String -Path clm-server-test.txt -Pattern "#(S****)"
```

I want to get only that characters matching the pattern, but it returns also characters before and after that string.

For example :

I have a registration set that starts with

```
S32145 thomas
S12345 bedro
S09867 stephane
```

with the `Select-String` command I want it to show me all the `S ***` words, not the names.

Comment: Just search for the string you want: `(S\d+)`

Answer (score 3):

- [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string)'s `-Pattern` parameter by default expects a [*regex* (regular expression)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions) to search for.

  - `"#(S****)"` is *not a valid regex* (it looks more like a *wildcard expression*, except that you'd use `?` to match a single character).
  - To match just the tokens that start with `S` followed by 5 digits, use `S\d{5}`, or, to match any number of digits, use `S\d+`, as [TheIncorrigible1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8188846/theincorrigible1) suggests.
    Also, you could refine the regex to match only at word boundaries (`\b`): `'\bS\d{5}\b'`
- `Select-String` doesn't support outputting *just* the matching parts of lines, but you can do that by further processing the [`[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.commands.matchinfo) instances that it outputs.

To put it all together:

```
Select-String -Path clm-server-test.txt -Pattern '\bS\d{5}\b' | 
  ForEach-Object { $_.Matches[0].Value }
```

With your sample input this yields:

```
S32145
S12345
S09867
```

---

As an aside: As evident from the command above, `Select-String` currently doesn't make it easy to extract just the matching parts of the input lines.
If you're interested in having a switch introduced that simplifies this, [participate in the discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7712).

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your answer and for yours in fact, your order to bring me closer to the expected result except that, I would like him to return to me that the word that begins with a "S ***" until now point on the line in all things that I would like to avoid.

I would like him to see me the number "S7676583"

Thank you so much